# rsync over ssh backup failing sometimes with code 20

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, backup

I have backup script running by crontab on a remote server. It pulls data from a local server through ssh.
Here's the script rsync line:

*rsync --delete --stats -h -av -e ssh root@$1:$2 $3 > $syncdata 2>> $log*

It works fine most of time, but sometimes it fails with the following stderr from rsync:

*rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at io.c(513) [sender=3.1.2]*

Any ideas on why does it fail?

And also can someone please explain what is *io.c(513)* in the error message?

Comment: The `io.c(513)` refers to where the `rsync` program was executing at the time of receiving the signal that terminated it, i.e. on line 513 in the `io.c` source code file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Kusalananda. So, now I see it definitely has to do something with storage i/o capacity. Could this error be caused by too slow/overloaded storage on the remote host?

Comment: You can ask for many levels of debug logging on the remote. To start with add `-M --log-file=/tmp/log` to get a log file on the remote sender of what it is doing. If that is not enough look at all the `--debug=...` levels you can ask for.

Comment: Thank you @meuh, I definitely will give debug level logging a shot.